# MSword - How to use find and replace to conduct advanced replacing

Tags: replace, ms-word, find

I have a document with many regression tables. The p values are denoted for every coefficient as "p = 0.xxx". This makes the tables look ugly and messy. How do I implement find and replace in MSWord so that I can change the denotation of p values from "p = 0.xxx" to "(0.xxx)"?

Though I can do half the job by replacing "p = " with "(", however, for the closing bracket, I still have to do it manually. Given there are several tables, this halfway solution does not do the job for me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this is what you want?

```vb
Sub ReplaceText_MSword__How_to_use_find_and_replace_to_conduct_advanced_replacing()
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "p = 0.([0-9]{3})"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = "(0.\1)"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
End Sub
```